# Why are Windows functions in D extern?

Tags: windows, winapi, d

Inside the [WinAPI example](https://github.com/D-Programming-Language/dmd/blob/master/samples/winsamp.d) for D, I noticed a lot of it's functions are 'tagged' as `extern`. Why is this? The functions clearly aren't `extern`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `extern` keyword specifies the linkage. `WinMain` must have external linkage so that it can be accessed from outside the module. It also specifies (in parentheses) the calling convention to use when calling a method. This is called the [LinkageType](http://dlang.org/attribute.html#linkage). Detailed information can be found at [Interfacing to C - D Programming Language](http://dlang.org/interfaceToC.html).

Answer (score 2):

it means the function should be called with the windows calling convention which is different from the D calling convention

WinMain gets called from outside D so it must be able to get called from there